# Query Builder problema con los string

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos, querybuilder

Estoy intentando hacer esta consulta y se la traga sin problemas, pero no se actualiza la base de datos, por lo que he detectado, los string no los pone entre comillas. ¿que puedo hacer?

```
// Se guarda todo en la base de datos de oferta
        \DB::table('offers')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->update(['name' => $name, 'vacant' => $vacant, 'startDate' => $startDate, 'endDate' => $endDate, 'description' => $description, 'area_id' => $area_id, ]);

        return response()->json($offer, 200);
```

// Lo que envia el front

```
update `offers` set `name` = Pruie, `vacant` = 16, `startDate` = 1973-03-20, `endDate` = 2003-11-22, `description` = Similique fugit eaque non nostrum cum aut nesciunt. Iusto dolore quidem eius repellat esse. Non sequi occaecati est commodi., `area_id` = 15 where `id` = 1;
```

Esa es lo que mando el front, y por lo que veo lo que único raro son las comillas de los string, lo pongo en sql y le pongo comillas y se lo come.

Comment: ¿Seguro que esas variables si tienen un valor asignado cuando ejecutas el update?

Comment: Actualizada la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

es posible que tengas que sanitizar las variables que sean string, puedes utilizar el propio CI para ello, sustituyendo la $variable por

```
$this->db->escape($variable)
```

Un saludo

Comment: La pregunta es sobre Laravel y no CI